# Template specialization for own smart pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, template-specialization

I have my own smart pointer class realization.

```
template<class Pointee>
class SmartPtr {
private:
    Pointee* _pointee;
    SmartPtr(SmartPtr &);
public:
    explicit SmartPtr(Pointee * pt = 0);
    ~SmartPtr();
    SmartPtr& operator=(SmartPtr&);
    operator Pointee*() const { return _pointee; }
    bool operator!() const { return _pointee != 0; }
    bool defined() const { return _pointee != 0; }
    Pointee* operator->() const { return _pointee; }
    Pointee& operator*() const { return *_pointee; }
    Pointee* get() const { return _pointee; }
    Pointee* release();
    void reset(Pointee * pt = 0);
};

template<class Pointee>
class SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Pointee>> {
private:
    Pointee* _pointee;
    SmartPtr(SmartPtr &);
public:
    explicit SmartPtr(SmartPtr<Pointee> * pt = 0);
    ~SmartPtr();
    SmartPtr& operator=(SmartPtr&);
    operator Pointee*() const { return *_pointee; }
    bool operator!() const { return _pointee != 0; }
    bool defined() const { return _pointee != 0; }
    Pointee& operator->() const { return _pointee; }
    Pointee& operator*() const { return *_pointee; }
    Pointee* get() const { return _pointee; }
    Pointee* release();
    void reset(Pointee * pt = 0);
};

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr &spt) :_pointee(spt.release()) {
    return;
}

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::SmartPtr(Pointee * pt) : _pointee(pt) {
    return;
}

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Pointee>>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr<Pointee>* pt) : _pointee(pt) {
    return;
}

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::~SmartPtr() {
    delete _pointee;
}

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>& SmartPtr<Pointee>::operator=(SmartPtr &source)
{
    if (&source != this)
        reset(source.release());
    return *this;
}

template<class Pointee>
Pointee * SmartPtr<Pointee>::release() {
    Pointee* oldSmartPtr = _pointee;
    _pointee = 0;
    return oldSmartPtr;
}

template<class Pointee>
void SmartPtr<Pointee>::reset(Pointee * pt) {
    if (_pointee != pt)
    {
        delete _pointee;
        _pointee = pt;
    }
    return;
}
```

The idea of this it's that I can do this:

```
SmartPtr<SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>>> sp3(new SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>>(new SmartPtr<Time>(new Time(0, 0, 1))));
```

***`Time`*** it's my own class for testing. It has method `hours()` which show in console count of hours I set in constructor.

And I can display hours in console like this:

```
cout << sp2->hours() << endl;
```

Instead of:

```
cout << sp3->operator->()->operator->()->hours() << endl;
```

I can do this because I have first class in which in `opertor->()` I return `Pointee*`.

```
template<class Pointee>
    class SmartPtr {...}
```

And

```
template<class Pointee>
class SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Pointee>> {...}
```

Where in `opertor->()` I return `Pointee &`.

But there are some errors I can't fix.

```
Error C2440 initialization: can not be converted "SmartPtr<Time> *" in "Time *" 
Error C2439 SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>>::_pointee: unable to initialize member
```

Comment: Why do you want any of this?

Comment: Just for fun but I stuck on this problem

Comment: Doesn't look like fun to me at all. More like a trainwreck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to obtain an `operator->()` that recursively extract the `SmartPtr` to obtain the inner no-`SmartPtr` pointer ... I think that you should avoid to specialize the `SmartPtr` class, for `SmartPtr` template argument, but you have to "specialize" the `operator->()`

I mean...

(1) delete the `SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Pointee>>` specialization

(2) before the `SmartPtr` implementation, develop a type-traits to detect if `Pointee` is a `SmartPtr`, by example

```
template <typename>
class SmartPtr;

template <typename>
struct isSP : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename P>
struct isSP<SmartPtr<P>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

(3) demand the real execution of `operator->()` to another function that you choose through tag-dispatching, by example

```
auto const operator->() const
 { return getPtr(isSP<Pointee>{}); }
```

(4) implement the different versions of the dispatched function to be recursive in the true case and to return the pointer in the false case, by example

```
auto const getPtr (std::true_type const &) const 
 { return _pointee->operator->(); }

auto const getPtr (std::false_type const &) const 
 { return _pointee; }
```

Now (in `main()`) you can write `

```
std::cout << sp3->hours() << std::endl;
```

(but are you sure it's a good idea?)

Anyway... unfortunately this solution use the `auto` return type for `getPtr()` and `operator->()` so this work only from C++14; if you want a C++11 (or C++98) solution, it's a little more complicated.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
class SmartPtr;

template <typename>
struct isSP : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename P>
struct isSP<SmartPtr<P>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template<class Pointee>
class SmartPtr {
private:
    Pointee* _pointee;
    SmartPtr(SmartPtr &);
public:
    explicit SmartPtr(Pointee * pt = 0);
    ~SmartPtr();
    SmartPtr& operator=(SmartPtr&);
    operator Pointee*() const { return _pointee; }
    bool operator!() const { return _pointee != 0; }
    bool defined() const { return _pointee != 0; }


    auto const getPtr (std::true_type const &) const 
     { return _pointee->operator->(); }

    auto const getPtr (std::false_type const &) const 
     { return _pointee; }

    auto const operator->() const
     { return getPtr(isSP<Pointee>{}); }


    Pointee& operator*() const { return *_pointee; }
    Pointee* get() const { return _pointee; }
    Pointee* release();
    void reset(Pointee * pt = 0);
};

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr &spt) :_pointee(spt.release()) {
    return;
}

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::SmartPtr(Pointee * pt) : _pointee(pt) {
    return;
}

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>::~SmartPtr() {
    delete _pointee;
}

template<class Pointee>
SmartPtr<Pointee>& SmartPtr<Pointee>::operator=(SmartPtr &source)
{
    if (&source != this)
        reset(source.release());
    return *this;
}

template<class Pointee>
Pointee * SmartPtr<Pointee>::release() {
    Pointee* oldSmartPtr = _pointee;
    _pointee = 0;
    return oldSmartPtr;
}

template<class Pointee>
void SmartPtr<Pointee>::reset(Pointee * pt) {
    if (_pointee != pt)
    {
        delete _pointee;
        _pointee = pt;
    }
    return;
}


struct Time
 {
   int a, b, c;

   Time (int a0, int b0, int c0) : a{a0}, b{b0}, c{c0}
    { }

   int hours () const
    { return a; }
 };


int main ()
 {
   SmartPtr<SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>>>
      sp3(new SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Time>>(new SmartPtr<Time>(new Time(0, 0, 1))));

   std::cout << sp3->hours() << std::endl;    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 50 you have:

```
SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Pointee>>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr<Pointee>* pt) : _pointee(pt) {
```

which should probably be

```
SmartPtr<SmartPtr<Pointee>>::SmartPtr(SmartPtr<Pointee>* pt) : _pointee(pt->get()) {
```

Also, it looks like you're missing a destructor implementation for your specialized SmartPtr-to-SmartPtr version.

But finally, it must be said that

### What you're doing here is just all wrong. This is bad, confusing code and I strongly advise you not to use it.